# Responsive/fluid height to fit any screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a page that shows something like a business card, with a picture and some attributes of the person. I got a fluid width but I would like that the height could be fluid as well, I mean the card adapts no matter the screen size. Any Idea?
Here is my html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="my-page">
<div data-role="header"> 
    <h1>Page Title</h1> 
</div> 
 <div data-role="content" id="busCard">
    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div style="text-align:center" id="personName">John Doe</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><img id="personPic" alt="alt..." src="http://static0.therichestimages.com/wp-content/uploads/jack-nicholson-classical_160255-1920x1200.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div id="personCat" style="text-align: center">CEO</div></div>
    </div>

    <ul id="my-listview" class="my-breakpoint" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false">
        <li>
            <a>
            <h2>link1</h2>
            <div class="ui-li-aside">
                <h2 style="margin:-5px -20px 0px 0px;">OOO</h2>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
            <h2>link1</h2>
            <div class="ui-li-aside">
                <h2 style="margin:-5px -20px 0px 0px;">OOO</h2>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
            <h2>link1</h2>
            <div class="ui-li-aside">
                <h2 style="margin:-5px -20px 0px 0px;">OOO</h2>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
            <h2>link1</h2>
            <div class="ui-li-aside">
                <h2 style="margin:-5px -20px 0px 0px;">OOO</h2>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
            <h2>link1</h2>
            <div class="ui-li-aside">
                <h2 style="margin:-5px -20px 0px 0px;">OOO</h2>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
            <h2>link1</h2>
            <div class="ui-li-aside">
                <h2 style="margin:-5px -20px 0px 0px;">OOO</h2>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>   
    </ul>   
</div>
<div data-role="footer"> 
    <h1>footer</h1> 
</div> 
</div>
```

and my css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 35em) {
        .ui-grid-solo img{
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
        }
    }

    #my-page .ui-content, #my-listview {
        min-height : 100%;
        height     : 100%;
        margin     : 0;
        padding    : 0;
    }

    #my-listview .ui-li {
        height : 20%;
    }
    #my-listview {
        padding : 10px;
    }

    #my-listview .ui-btn{


padding:0em;
    margin: 0em;  0em; 0em; 0em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
#my-listview h2{
            margin-left:15px;
        }

    #my-listview{
        height: 20%;
        float: none;
        padding-top:0px;
    }  
#busCard {
            border-style:solid;
        border-color:red;
        border-width:5px;
}
.ui-grid-solo{
text-align:center;
width: 100% !important;
}
```

And a jsfiddle link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvw2E/)

thanks!

Comment: How about reducing image's height for smaller screens?

Comment: My experience is javascript might be easier than css in terms of fluid height

Answer (score 0):

You can set the main wrapper value.

```
#my-page {
       position: absolute;
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       }
```

and then put content inside. Second, not need to give em, px etc for zero (0) value. Like you do above "margin : 0em, 0em, 0em, 0em" just type it "margin: 0"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing as height is not really a fluid layout.  Also your CSS is very messy.

But basically if you remove every height attribute you have set including the min-height and simply update this line, it will look perfect.

```
  #my-page .ui-content, #my-listview {
        height : auto;   
        margin     : 0;
        padding    : 0; 

    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: sorry about the messy css and thanks for the answer but I couldn't get your result. Now the picture is covering the entire screen.

Comment: #personPic {width:400px;height:300px;} - Add this